# Can I see phase diagram for a number of solutions of quadratic equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Must be simple, but haven't found it on the internet. Let's say we have equation $x^{2} + px + q = 0$. Can we see the 2d graph with areas where we have $0$,$1$ or $2$ solutions?

Comment: Unnamed01, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question. Moreover, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The number and 'types' of solutions for a quadratic equation $x^2 + px + q= 0$ are determined by the roots of the function $f(x)= x^2 + px + q$. Of course, we can determine the number of distinct roots and the 'type' of roots of a quadratic function from its determinant. We know the determinant of quadratic function $ax^2 + bx + c$, where we take $a, b, c$ to be real numbers, is $D= b^2 - 4ac$. We know that if...
$$
\begin{cases}
D > 0, & \text{there are two, distinct real solutions.} \\
D= 0, & \text{there is one real solution (with multiplicity two).} \\
D < 0, & \text{there are two, distinct complex solutions.}
\end{cases}
$$

In your case with $f(x)= x^2 + px + q$, we have $a= 1$, $b= p$, and $c= q$. So we have $D= b^2 - 4ac= p^2 - 4q$. This is what one would need to plot to determine the nature of the solutions graphically. So let's take the independent variable to be $q$ and set this equal to $0$ (the 'border' for the different types of behavior). We then have $q= \frac{p^2}{4}= \left( \frac{p}{2} \right)^2$. This is a parabola in the $qp$-plane.

If $D > 0$, there are two, distinct real solutions. But then $p^2 - 4q > 0$ so that $q < \frac{p^2}{4}$. This is the region 'outside' the resulting parabola $q= \frac{p^2}{4}$. The case where $D= 0$, there is one distinct real solution. But then $p^2 - 4q= 0$ so that $q= \frac{p^2}{4}$. This is the resulting parabola. Finally, if $D < 0$, there are two, distinct complex solutions. But then $p^2 - 4q < 0$ so that $q > \frac{p^2}{4}$. This is the region 'inside' the resulting parabola.

[image: Root Plots]

Comment: Please, do not answer very low-quality questions.